# A non-constant polynomial with odd-integer co-efficients and of even degree , has no rational root?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, roots

Let $f(x)$ be a non-constant polynomial in $\mathbb Z[x]$ with odd-integer co-efficients and even degree ; then is it true that $f$ has no rational root ?

Comment: No. $f(x)=x^2-1.$

Comment: The coefficient of $x$ is $0$ which is even, so that isn't a valid counter-example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x) = a_{2n}x^{2n} + \cdots + a_1x + a_0$ be a polynomial with odd integer coefficients. By the rational root test, any rational root of $f(x)$ is of the form $c/d$ where $c$ divides $a_0$ and $d$ divides $a_{2n}$. Since $a_0$ and $a_{2n}$ are odd, so are $c$ and $d$. We have
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}} a_{2n}\left(\frac{c}{d}\right)^{2n} + a_{2n-1}\left(\frac{c}{d}\right)^{2n-1} + \cdots + a_1\left(\frac{c}{d}\right) + a_0 \\
&=\frac{a_{2n}c^{2n} + a_{2n-1}c^{2n-1}d + \cdots + a_1cd^{2n-1} + a_0d^{2n}}{d^{2n}} \\
&=0,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
hence
$$a_{2n}c^{2n} + a_{2n-1}c^{2n-1}d + \cdots + a_1cd^{2n-1} + a_0d^{2n} = 0.$$
Now since each $a_i$ and $c$ and $d$ are odd, so is each integer in the above sum. So we have an odd number of odd integers summing to zero, which is a clear contradiction.

Comment: Very clear and easy to follow, good job!